# C# Square Pattern printing with overlapping

Tags: c#

When provided with multiple integers representing the length of several squares, the returned
String will be the representation of multiple squares sharing the top left corner, overlapping each
other when needed.

E.g.
Input: 3,5
Output:

```
#####
# # #
### #
#   #
#####
```

I tried this code but for one input only. I tried to place `Console.SetCursorPosition` but only prints the second input. May I know what can I be missing?

```
string[] edgesArr = edges.Split(',');

foreach(string edge in edgesArr) {
    PrintSquare(Convert.ToInt32(edge));
}


static void PrintSquare(int edges) {

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < edges; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < edges; j++) {

            if (i == 0 || i == edges-1 || j == 0 || j == edges-1) {
                Console.Write('#');
            } else {
                Console.Write(' ');
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: _"but only prints the second input"_ - because the "second" input is printed after the first, thus overwriting the previous value.

Comment: yes, this is why I think that setting the cursor position won't fit. and am asking if there's something the in the square printing code that can meet the requirement.

Comment: You actually want to determine if a given position should be `#` or empty. To do so you would need to check the edges to determine if any of them need to be drawn in that location.

Comment: If you want to do the console set cursor position approach then you'll need to use that whenever you want to move the cursor, and not print spaces. (But I wouldn't, I'd go for Llama's approach.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to print overlappers in descending order, first print 5, then 3 and so on.

```cs
int[] edgesArr = edges.Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s));
Array.Sort(edgesArr);
Array.Reverse(edgesArr);
foreach(int edge in edgesArr)
{
   PrintSquare(edge);
}
```